# How would I know I am using Always Free Tier or Paid Account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console, google-alerts

I have finished used the google free trial and it prompt me to upgrade account for always free tier, when I clicked upgrade and it successfully upgraded. But how can i check my next project is under always free tier or paid account?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a billing / product support question.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure your project is using the Always Free Tier you have to link it to your [Always Free](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free) billing account. You can see this on the Google Cloud Console under [Billing](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/view-history), in the Overview page.

Also, when you create a new project, you are prompt for a billing account. At that step, select this Always Free account.